# SOAP API and PHP

Tags: php, xml, api, soap

I'm having a problem calling a SOAP client with PHP.

The SOAP info I was given is completely raw, no file just the SOAP client's code

```
POST /exptapi/exptsms.asmx HTTP/1.1
 Host: www.experttexting.com
  Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://www.experttexting.com/QueryBalance"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"          xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
<QueryBalance xmlns="http://www.experttexting.com">
  <UserID>string</UserID>
  <PWD>string</PWD>
  <APIKEY>string</APIKEY>
</QueryBalance>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
<QueryBalanceResponse xmlns="http://www.experttexting.com">
  <QueryBalanceResult>xml</QueryBalanceResult>
</QueryBalanceResponse>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

my problem is I don't know what do with it...what type of file should I save this as?

And I'm using

```
  <?
   $client = new soapclient("/*the file I want to call should go here but I don't know     what to do with the soap code provided*/");
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not too sure what is being asked here... but this may help.

Build the client on the WebService Description Language (WSDL)

[Soap Client Constructor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php)

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient("https://www.experttexting.com/exptapi/exptsms.asmx?WSDL");
?>
```